# Crop an image with a different screen resolution

Tags: c#, .net

What I need is to crop images at the same place but with different resolution.

For example:

Image 1 created with  1024 x 768

Image 2 created with 1440 x 900

Now I have to crop images but at the same place let's say it will be

X = 10%
Y = 10%
WIDTH = 30%
HEIGHT = 20%

I use the following code to do it but it doesn't work like I need.

Any clue?

THANK YOU!!!

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int w = 0;
int h = 0;

int inputX = 10;
int inputY = 10;
int inputW = 20;
int inputH = 30;

x = int.Parse(Math.Round(decimal.Parse((__Bitmap.Width * inputX / 100).ToString()), 0).ToString());
y = int.Parse(Math.Round(decimal.Parse((__Bitmap.Height * inputY / 100).ToString()), 0).ToString());

w = int.Parse(Math.Round(decimal.Parse((__Bitmap.Width * inputW / 100).ToString()), 0).ToString());
h = int.Parse(Math.Round(decimal.Parse((__Bitmap.Height * inputH / 100).ToString()), 0).ToString());

Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(x, y, w,h);
Bitmap bmpCrop = __Bitmap.Clone(cropArea, __Bitmap.PixelFormat);
```

I mean if there technically logic to do it?

I guess I can do like (pseudo-code)

```
if (Resolution == "1024x768")
    int inputX = 10;
    int inputY = 10;
    int inputW = 20;
    int inputH = 30;
else if (Resolution == "1440x900")
    int inputX = 8;
    int inputY = 8;
    int inputW = 19;
    int inputH = 28;

 and etc...
```

I am not sure of there is any coefficient to recalculate % depending on resolution to do it... It is like a [crop-factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crop_factor).

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: Why do you use string conversion? it's a simple math...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but does calculating images centers and 'moving' from that point left/right/up/down as you want won't be easier? Please, provide image explanation/examples, so I could help.

Comment: Look I want to crop image in place where there some object lets say a CAT. So I use %% to define the area. But for another resolution I have to use different %%. That's a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty example of what I mean by, you'll always get the same image section, when calculating your crop window with percentages:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 100x80 image
        Image asdf = Image.FromFile("asdf.bmp", true);

        // twice the size, 200x160
        Image asdf2 = Image.FromFile("asdf2.bmp", true);

        // same image, different aspect ratio: 200x80
        Image asdf3 = Image.FromFile("asdf3.bmp", true);

        Bitmap asdfBmp = new Bitmap(asdf);
        Bitmap asdf2Bmp = new Bitmap(asdf2);
        Bitmap asdf3Bmp = new Bitmap(asdf3);

        pictureBox1.Image = cropImage(asdfBmp);
        pictureBox2.Image = cropImage(asdf2Bmp);
        pictureBox3.Image = cropImage(asdf3Bmp);
    }

    private Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap sourceBitmap)
    {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        double w = 0;
        double h = 0;

        double inputX = 10;
        double inputY = 10;
        double inputW = 50;
        double inputH = 50;

        // integer division " 10 / 100 " will return 0, use doubles or floats.
        // furthermore you don't have to convert anything to a string or back here.
        x = sourceBitmap.Width * inputX / 100.0;
        y = sourceBitmap.Height * inputY / 100.0;

        w = sourceBitmap.Width * inputW / 100.0;
        h = sourceBitmap.Height * inputH / 100.0;

        // casting to int will just cut off all decimal places. you could also round.
        Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h);
        return sourceBitmap.Clone(cropArea, sourceBitmap.PixelFormat);
    }
}
```

Sources:

[image: asdf.bmp]
[image: asdf2.bmp]
[image: asdf3.bmp]

Result:

[image: Result]

As you can see, all result images show the same section of the image. So I either still don't get what you're aiming at, or your error must be somewhere else.

Considering your unnecessary type conversions and integer division bug, you should perhaps have a look at a [c# tutorial about types](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/lesson02.aspx).

Comment: You're welcome. But then I don't get what you want to know. You are already using percentages to determine the position and size of your window, so you will get the same image in different sizes when applying your code to two images that show the same object in different resolutions.If you have an image that's 100 pixels wide and an object is shown in this image at pixel 50, that's at 50%. Now you resize the image so it's 200 pixels wide, your object will be at pixel 100, that's still at 50% of the image's width.

Comment: See... When I calculate crop rectangle in %%% to get face for 1024x768 then I am getting it if i use THE SAME %%% to get this face for the image with different resolution I get a half of the face. Because I need to use DIFFERENT %%% to calculate correct position in pixels to create crop rectangle. My idea to use the same %%% but RECALCULATE SOMEHOW crop rectangle for different resolutions and probably to use some coefficient to do it.

Comment: I still don't get it. You have a crop rectangle which's position and size are given percentually by the size of the original image. So no matter how big your image is, if you cut out an area given by the calculated crop rectangle, it will show the same section of your original image. If you still need help please provide an image example of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the center of the crop. I assume that you get somehow the required x,y,w,h values. Then this center point need to be recalculated to the center of the second image: i.e. if the center is [25;50], then for the 1024x768 image it is respectively [25/1024;50/768], which gives [2.44%;6.51%]. So on the second image, let's say 1440x900 it gives us [1440*2.44%;900*6.51%] => [35;59] in pixels of course.

Now you need width and height of the new image. If the aspect ratio is the same it is easy, because you can calculate dimensions as a `cropWidth/firstImageWidth*secondImageWidth`, but otherwise you need to multiply it by the correct aspect ratio.

Anyway I don't think you understand the problem. If the aspect ratios of similar images are different, it is either different part of the image or image is distorted.

Below I've corrected your example. I won't explain it because it's quite obvious.. I hope. Just take a look at the parts covered by the transparent black and white areas...

[image]